# Cordova sound bug on android

Tags: android, cordova, audio

i made a simple android app with cordova to play audio whenever a button is clicked. it works on my huawei phone (android 5.1.1) and the google emulator, but it does NOT work on any other android phones (android 4.x [4.1;4.2;4.4]).

i have the media plugin installed into the project, haven't done any android-version specific restrictions

index.js: http://puu.sh/mrY3g/9d4a99d3e9.txt
config.xml: http://puu.sh/mrY7a/ae9b06aa51.txt

thanks a lot
ps. if u need more files for investigation/troubleshooting, leave a comment :)

## EDIT

It was something with Content Security Policy, fixed that, but now when i logcat my phone, when i try to play the .mp3 file, it says Permission Denied. This happens ONLY on android 4.x (On browser and android 5 works perfectly). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't link to external resources in your question-  there's every chance that the lifetime of them will be shorter than your question.

Comment: if you think it's a bug, file an issue on issues.cordova.io providing all the information you can (cordova CLI version, cordova android version, etc)

Comment: and about the android version... i haven't done any changes to the config. can you tell me how to add the min. sdk, amx. sdk, target sdk (if there are)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way sound is played from onclick(function a)  where in a() was made an audio/media control (backend) which played the sound. now i made an <audio> control in the html and via javascript i play it